# SQL Query to concatenate strings or add default value

Tags: sql, string, concatenation

I have to create a View that shows a field created by concatenating some other fields. The simple query that I use is this one:

```
SELECT     
    CODPROY, DESCPROY, USER, CODPROY + ' - ' + USER + ' - ' + DESCPROY AS Expr
FROM    
    dbo.PROY
```

The problem is that USER may be NULL and in this case I have to insert a default text, something like 'NOT AVAILABLE'. Can this be done in a view?

Comment: It's SQL Server, sorry. Anyway I prefer a standard SQL solution portable to several RDBMs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) if you are using SQL Server

```
SELECT 
  CODPROY, 
  DESCPROY, 
  USER, 
  CODPROY + ' - ' + COALESCE(USER,'NOT AVAILABLE') + ' - ' + DESCPROY AS Expr 
FROM dbo.PROY
```

Comment: Love your solution using Transact SQL commands. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done. You need to use [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) (mySQL) or something like it ..

```
CREATE VIEW foobar as 
SELECT CODPROY
      , DESCPROY
      , USER
      , CODPROY + ' - ' + IFNULL(USER,'DEFAULT') + ' - ' + DESCPROY AS Expr 
 FROM dbo.PROY;
```

Comment: I don't think it's MySQL, since it doesn't allow '+' for concatenation.